# Which Apache-modules must I enable?

Tags: apache, linux

I'm running a VPS with `Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64` and Apache `2.4.7`, and would like to set-up a WordPress site on it.  Which apache-modules *must* I have enabled - and which *should* I enable (eg. for cool WP-features)?  Are there any modules I absolutely should *not* enable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the list of minimum Apache modules which is required to run WordPress websites.

```
mod_alias
mod_authz_host
mod_deflate
mod_dir
mod_expires
mod_headers
mod_mime
mod_rewrite
mod_log_config
mod_autoindex
mod_negotiation
mod_setenvif
```

Comment: I put these in my Dockerfile using the 7-apache image which uses Debian Stretch and it couldn't find mod_log_config.

Comment: Is this list up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Of the list above, these are definitely not required (although they could be useful).

mod_deflate
mod_expires
mod_mime

Others might also be able to be omitted, depending on what you're doing and what you want to give up.

Answer (score 0):

The question asked is older but still relevant and this thread still comes up today in search results. Researching for my own understanding, I hope the following info updates & helps.

Referencing CloudLinux 8.4 & 7.8 with Cpanel v100.x servers and EasyApache4.

Checked Apache loaded modules with #apachectl -M and compared the enabled modules with the list and presented options in EA4.

To update the module list:
:not offered in EA4 - appear to be installed / enabled by default in apachectl
mod_alias; mod_authz_host; mod_dir.

:offered in EA4 and were already enabled on the two reference servers.
mod_expires; mod_headers; mod_mime; mod_rewrite; mod_log_config; mod_autoindex;
mod_negotiation; mod_setenvif.

In EA4 these could be useful:
mod_brotli : https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/apache/apache-module-brotli/

mod_cgi /mod_cgid / mod_fcgid : https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/apache/apache-module-fcgid/ - lots of caveats with this one - the test servers had mod_cgi eabled on one and mod-cgid on the other - not sure how these were enabled - further review needed

mod_deflate :: Enable - relates to Optimize Website tool : html / txt file compression to enhance site speed via Apache. Ref https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/software/optimize-website/  - Also review Gzip compression options in WHM->Tweak Settings - check vCPU count defaults to 1 - increase to add CPU's (max = total CPU's)

mod_expires :: Enabled by default - Ref https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/1500008232181-How-to-set-Expires-Headers-for-Your-Site-on-cPanel

There are more but I'll review another day.

Comment: That's useful, but ss EasyApache4 that much different to Apache 2.4? I'd assume the module lists were the same.

Comment: There is no difference in the modules, as far as I know, Cpanel are not tweaking Apache code directly. EA4 is a configuration tool for Apache on CPanel/WHM servers. The question relates specifically to configuring for Wordpress sites in that environment.